# child id and parent id mapping in same sql table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get the column named listCode by writing below query but it is coming as empty.
In this query I am trying to map parentid to listid in same table and get only those parent records in listcode column

```
SELECT ListCode FROM mytable WHERE ListType = 'CNT' AND ListId =
(SELECT ParentId  FROM mytable WHERE ListType = 'CNT')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that these entries are present in the DB by exporting the DB file and viewing it with an SQLite viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with IN:

```
SELECT ListCode FROM mytable
WHERE
  WHERE ListType = 'CNT'
  AND 
  ListId IN (SELECT Parentid FROM mytable)
```

or with EXISTS:

```
SELECT m.ListCode FROM mytable m
WHERE
  WHERE m.ListType = 'CNT'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable
    WHERE Parentid = m.ListId
)
```